# How to create database,table with primary key and auto increment in SQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I would like to create a table that they have an ID int primary key, However, I would like to insert the values manually, that means I don't need the ID incremented by itself?

Comment: Not clear to me what you're asking. (Title suggests you want auto-increment, text suggests you don't.  No indication of what you've tried and in what way it hasn't worked.)

Comment: Sorry! I couldn't find how to alter my question, as it suppose to be "NO" in front of Incrementd, thank you.

Comment: You can always [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL these are totally different concepts.

1. you have primary keys
2. You have sequence generators that can generate ints.  A serial type is an int that gets its value from a sequence generator.

The two have nothing to do with eachouther.

Yes you can:

```
CREATE TABLE a (b int primary key);
```

You can also

```
CREATE TABLE a (b serial);
```

You can of course do both

```
CREATE TABLE a (b serial primary key);
```